# Uploaded images unreadable due to headers being appended before the body

Tags: cordova, file-transfer

In my cordova app, I am uploading images to the server using FileTransfer plugin.

After uploading the image, I opened the file but with no success. I examined the file by opening it using a text editor and I found out that there is a "content-length" on top of the file. I tried to delete it and save, after that the image is now working properly.

So I checked the plugin's code and found this piece:

```
    [postBodyBeforeFile appendData:formBoundaryData];
    [postBodyBeforeFile appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBodyBeforeFile appendData:[val dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postBodyBeforeFile appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding : NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

...

```
    [postBodyBeforeFile appendData:formBoundaryData];
    [postBodyBeforeFile appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", fileKey, fileName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    if (mimeType != nil) {
        [postBodyBeforeFile appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: %@\r\n", mimeType] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
    [postBodyBeforeFile appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Length: %d\r\n\r\n", [fileData length]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

after discovering the cause, I commented out all "postBodyBeforeFile" and it is working fine now. But I know this is not the best solution as it may affect some part of my application.

I want to know what could possibly cause this issue?
Is this a known bug? What is the permanent solution?

Thanks.

**cordova version: 2.9.1 
**attaching images:
[image: content of the file]
[image]

Comment: try using multipart form and ajax for uploading files.

Comment: I am using cordova plugin FileTransfer which uses `ft.upload()` , and this defaults to `multipart/form-data`